# Android Studio libgdx multiplayer

Tags: android, libgdx, multiplayer, turn-based, realtime

Does anyone know **if it's possible to setup a multiplayer game using libgdx in Android Studio?**

I've been trying to convert my game to multiplayer using all kinds of tutorials on libgdx & multiplayer but I'm guessing it's just not possible with android Studio. Seems it's only possible to add leaderboard and achievements?

If someone managed to get multiplayer working with libgdx in Android Studio please let me know. And perhaps explain how to get it working?

If someone knows it's **impossible** please let me know as well.

If impossible, is it worth trying eclipse? Since it's not supported by Google anymore...???

Thnx in advanced

Comment: I can confirm that GDX 1.5.6 does, indeed, work properly within Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2). I don't know what you mean about Google support but, generally speaking, it's probably safe to count on an eclipse-based, GDX*-like*, API continuing to exist for some time. As to being "worth it", it seems to me that most eclipse users fall into one of two categories: those that love it, and those that *tolerate* it, only when necessary.

Comment: Although I don't have any experience with Android Studio, I could attempt to Google my way to the information you need. Please be more specific about what's not working with networking, multiplayer, and/or the tutorials. Are you just trying to send basic multiplayer data back and forth?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, isn't Android Studio just an IDE? Why shouldn't it be possible to create a multiplayer game with it? I guess you just have to use an Android-Compatible networking library. Libgdx allready has some [Networking thing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Networking), but idk how good it is. [KryoNet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) seems to be a good library, which runs on Desktop + Android.

Answer (score -1):

Well since it's very hard to get documentation about multiplayer setup all i should say is try IntelliJ IDEA you'll get better doucmentation on there official page only drawback is if you're working on creating a cross platform game then only exception will be for iOS. You'll need to visit official website & if there is any plugin available for simple integration for networking for intellij. It's far more better solution than android studio or eclipse since the documentation is not enough.I hope you'll do further research on you're own.